# Typescript Return Types: explicit-module-boundary-types error

Tags: typescript, typescript-eslint

I'm trying to adjust from moving to Typescript from Node so I've setup a bunch of eslint's to help me:

I can't seem to understand the following eslint error:

Missing return type on function. [eslint@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v4.17.0/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-module-boundary-types.md)

This is my code, the error is raised on the sns function.

```
const sns = ({config, logger}: SNSInterface) => {
  const client = new SNSClient({endpoint: config.sns.endpoint});

  const publish = async ({message, topicArn}: PublishInterface) : Promise<void> => {
    const command = new PublishCommand({
      Message: JSON.stringify(message),
      TopicArn: topicArn,
    });
    logger.debug({message, topicArn}, 'Publishing SNS Message');
    const data = await client.send(command).catch((err) => {
      logger.error(err, 'Failed to send Topic ARN');
      throw err;
    });
    logger.debug({data}, 'Publishing SNS Message Results');
  };

  return {
    publish,
  };
};

export default sns;
```

While I can resolve it by adding:

```
interface SNSReturnInterface {
  publish: ({ message, topicArn }: PublishInterface) => Promise<void>;
}

const sns = ({config, logger}: SNSInterface): SNSReturnInterface => {
```

Is this really the best way to do this? I would think that Typescript should be fine with inferring this? If I wanted to add a parameter to the publish function, would that mean I would have to change the ReturnInterface definition every time too? I don't want to turn off the rule unless necessary. Appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `explicit-module-boundary-types` rule means that you need to explicitly tell Typescript what is being returned by the `sns` function.

In your sample you've defined the type of `publish`, but you haven't explicitly defined the return type of `sns` (`return { publish }`).

Typescript itself is completely okay with inferring these types, but the rule wants you to be explicit, which is why your second sample works.

If you want to allow Typescript to automatically infer these return types then you should be fine turning off that eslint rule.

Alternatively, if you'd rather keep the rule, but only define the types once, you can define the return types like you've done in your second sample, and omit them from the other places. This way you've got an explicit definition on your boundary type (the exported `sns` object), which Typescript can use to infer the type of `publish`.

Comment: Awesome thank you! if I wanted to add another parameter to publish - say targetArn, would I then need to add it to both:

```
interface SNSReturnInterface {
  publish: ({ message, topicArn, targetArn }: PublishInterface) => Promise<void>;
}
```
as well as the function definition?
```
const publish = async ({message, topicArn, targetArn}: PublishInterface) =>
```
Or is there a way I could omit the parameters from the ReturnInterface?

Comment: With the example that you've given, you should be able to specify the definition of `publish` in your `ReturnInterface` as `(publishParams: PublishInterface) => Promise<void>`, which would save you from having to respecify the properties of PublishInterface in many places.

i.e. There is no need to unwrap the publish function's parameter in the type definition if you've already specified that it is of type `PublishInterface`

Comment: Hmmm okay thank you! Still adjusting to typescript life! :D